# WARNING: Name of the hazelcast schema location is incorrect, using default

Tags: warnings, hazelcast

The warning level logs we receive while starting our application are below,

> [main()] starting... [OK] Sep 03, 2019 1:38:17 PM
>   com.hazelcast.config.AbstractXmlConfigHelper WARNING: Name of the
>   hazelcast schema location is incorrect, using default WARNING: An
>   illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal
>   reflective access by
>   com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer
>   (file:/home/abc/def/ghe/lib/thirdparty/hazelcast-3.12.jar) to field
>   sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys WARNING: Please consider
>   reporting this to the maintainers of
>   com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer WARNING: Use
>   --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
>   denied in a future release

How can ignore these WARNING  logs or how can change log level INFO?

Or is there any way you know?

Comment: Do you have an XML file ? Can you post it here ? Even just the start with the `hazelcast` section and `xsi:schemaLocation`

Comment: <hazelcast-client xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
                               http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-3.6.xsd" xmlns="httt
p://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config">
        <properties>
                <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</property>
        </properties>
        ****
    </connection-strategy>
</hazelcast-client>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning would be thrown, if you have a version mismatch between the XSD version in your hazelcast.xml file and the version of hazelcast (hazelcast jar file) you use in your application.

Recently, one of the tester complaint about same warning. While investigation I have found that her hazelcast.xml file has some different version of XSD as given below :

```
<hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config- 
   3.6.xsd">
```

Whereas in my machine, I was not getting that warning therefore, I just copy my namespace header as given below in her hazelcast.xml file and it fixed the problem for her.

```
<hazelcast
xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config 
    http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.12.xsd">
```

So please make sure you use the same version of XSD url in your hazelcast.xml file as hazelcast jar version.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<hazelcast-client xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xsi:schemaLocation="hazelcast.com/schema/client-config hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-3.6.xsd" 
                  xmlns="httt p://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config">
```

to

```
<hazelcast-client xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config hazelcast-client-config-3.12.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config">
```

It may be a cut&paste error, but in your comment the `xmlns` has 3 "t"s in the "http: section.

Or, since you're using 3.12, you could use YAML configuration.